# C++ Access violation when deleting array > 130046 elements?

Tags: c++, access-violation, delete-operator

I have a very bizarre problem. The following is the smallest bit of code that reproduces it.

```
int main(void)
{
class MyClass { 
public:
    int* ptr;
    MyClass(int i) 
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl;
        ptr = new int [i]; 
    };
    ~MyClass()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
        delete[] ptr;
    };
};
MyClass MyClassInstance(130047);
delete &MyClassInstance;
return 0;
};
```

I assume you wouldn't guess that if I replace 130047 with 130046, the app consistently **doesn't crash,** and with 130047 it consistently **crashes,** giving the 0xc0000005 code for Access violation.

The output is:

```
Constructor
Destructor
Destructor
```

so the destructor **gets called twice** (as one would expect). Is that the problem? But then why is *i<=130046* OK and *i>130046* not OK?!?

Obviously, this is a very simple example so I need not call the `delete` operator at all — but in reality I'm writing a much bigger project and I would rather decide when destructors are to be called. Or should I leave this to the compiler's discretion?

For the record, I'm running Windows 7, GNU GCC Compiler, my IDE is Code::Blocks, this is meant to be a simple console application… what other information should I include?

Thanks in advance!

vpprof

Comment: You don't `delete` objects allocated on the stack, since they are cleaned up automatically. Remove `delete` line and your code should work.

Comment: Why are you writing `delete &MyClassInstance;`? It wasn't allocated using `new`.

Comment: You can only `delete` something that was allocated with `new`. `delete &myClassInstance` is undefined behavior.

Comment: OK, so I could `delete myClassInstance` if it were, say, a pointer to an array of `myClass` objects allocated with `new`, right?

And I suppose 130046 is just a quasi-random number, which I shouldn't bother with?

Comment: @vpprof You would `delete` `MyClassInstance` if you had created it using `new`. And that number seems to be the result of undefined behavior, so unless you're interested in what the compilers doing for curiosity's sake, it's not worthwhile to give that specific number any importance. You violated assumptions that compiler made, and got weird problems as a result.

Comment: @vpprof No, if `myClassInstance` were "a pointer to an array of `myClass` objects allocated with `new`", you would need to `delete[]` it, not `delete` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your approach if you dynamically allocate your object, otherwise the destructor will be called automatically once your object leaves its scope and since you've already deleted it, it tries to delete an invalid pointer.

So either removing the delete or dynamically allocating your object will fix the issue:

```
MyClass *MyClassInstance = new MyClass(130047);
delete MyClassInstance;
```

or

```
MyClass MyClassInstance(130047);
} // leave scope
```

Comment: Thank you! Which way do you recommend in this instance? If I have only one object, should I allocate it dynamically?

Comment: If you just have one object, I'd recommend you use the second way (stack-allocated) so that you don't have to worry about de-allocating memory. Dynamic memory is usually helpful if you want to create variable sized arrays.